# When adding resources to a Tomcat server in Eclipse, what can be a resource?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

When I bring up the "Add and Remove" resource dialog to add things like .war files (I think war is an example), I would like to know what sort of things constitute "resources" and how Eclipse identifies them as such. I am working on a new project that has a fairly complex Maven build and it is not clear to me what exactly I am adding to Tomcat. Could a directory be a resource? A pom file?

I should mention that I see a SNAPSHOT file (actually, the thing named this seems to be a Windows folder which does not hold jars) as a resource that can be added but the build does not seem to be producing a war or jar file which is named in this way. What does get added if I choose to add this resource seems to be composed of a bunch of jars or wars.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of this dialog? Or at least more context around what, exactly, you're doing? The more details in the question, the better the answers can be (generally speaking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like entities other than jars can be added to a server.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you didn't create your project as "Dynamic Web Project", so Eclipse doesn't recognize it like a web project. Create new "Dynamic Web Project" or go to Properties -> Projects Facets and check Dynamic Web Module